# Can I install an NPM module from GitHub from a certain branch or tag?

Tags: node.js, github, tags, npm, installation

When I have now:

`"dependencies": {
  "mymodule": "owner/repo"
}`

or

`"dependencies": {
  "mymodule": "git+ssh://git@github.com/owner/repo.git"
}`

NPM installs the module from GitHub from the `master` branch.

Is there a way to tell NPM to install a certain tag or the HEAD of a branch other than `master`?

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "mymodule": "git+ssh://git@github.com/owner/repo.git#commit-ish"
}
```

> The commit-ish can be any tag, sha, or branch which can be supplied as an argument to git checkout. The default is master.